# How to sequence Throwable \/ List[Throwable \/ A] into Throwable \/ List[A] in scalaz?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm trying to figure out how to sequence a `Throwable \/ List[Throwable \/ A]` into a `Throwable \/ List[A]` in a cleanly, possibly using the `Traverse` instance for `List`, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the applicative for the `right` of `\/`. Right now, here is the non-typeclass solution I have:

```
import scalaz._
def readlines: Throwable \/ List[String] = ???
def parseLine[A]: Throwable \/ A = ???
def parseLines[A](line: String): Throwable \/ List[A] = {
  val lines = readlines
  lines.flatMap {
    xs => xs.reverse.foldLeft(right[Throwable, List[A]](Nil)) {
      (result, line) => result.flatMap(ys => parseA(line).map(a => a :: ys))
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sure there has to be a better way to implement `parseLines`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sequenceU` to transform `List[Throwable \/ String]` to `Throwable \/ List[String]` (it will preserve only first `Throwable`) and than you should just use `flatMap` like this:

```
def source: Throwable \/ List[Throwable \/ String] = ???
def result: Throwable \/ List[String] = source.flatMap{_.sequenceU}
```

You could also use `traverseU` instead of `map` + `sequenceU`:

```
def readlines: Throwable \/ List[String] = ???
def parseLine[A](s: String): Throwable \/ A = ???

def parseLines[A](): Throwable \/ List[A] =
  readlines flatMap { _ traverseU parseLine[A] }
```

Using for-comprehension:

```
def parseLines[A](): Throwable \/ List[A] =
  for {
    l <- readlines
    r <- l traverseU parseLine[A]
  } yield r
```

Comment: `traverseU` is nicer than `map` and then `sequenceU`.

Comment: Nice! This is exactly what I needed. Took me a while to find the right syntax import for scalaz 7.0.5. Adding `import scalaz.syntax.traverse._` picked up the necessary implicit.